# Build Docker Image with Java and Node.js together (Error : java: not found )

Tags: java, node.js, docker

I've an API application that run both node and java files(jar) together. When I run the application locally it works, but once I create a docker image for it, I got an error from the postman .

```
  parsingError: Command failed: java -jar Binary\***.jar -s Files\*** -v -j
/bin/sh: 1: java: not found
```

I believe that I'm missing the jave configuration in docker file but I don't know how to put the configuration for java and node together. any help will be appricatited!

Here is the Docker config.

```
FROM node:14.18.1

WORKDIR /code

ENV PORT 3000

COPY package.json /code/package.json

RUN npm install

COPY . /code

CMD ["node","app.js"]
```

Note: I'm using Temurin JDK

Comment: You could use `RUN apk --update add <package>` to add any package you want

Comment: @MB I've tried this. it shows when building the image '# /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found' –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe inside node:14.18.1 there is no java installed.

You have to add another step inside dockerfile:

RUN apk update && apk add openjdk(versionjdk)

Comment: I've tried this. it shows when building the image '# /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found'

Comment: ok, we need to find the correct linux distro of node:14.18.1 i tought was alpine

Comment: `node14.18.1` image is actually based on `FROM debian:buster-slim`. Therefore, you probably install java with `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install default-jdk`. If that doesn't work, maybe [this article](https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-debian-10/) can help.